# Ionic 3 modal navparams returning undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

So i'm trying to pass a string as a parameter to a Modal (master/detail specifically) and the Modal does open, but the string is returning undefined.

Here is the parent ts:

```
 editReminder(event, data){
    console.log(data);
    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ReminderDetailsPage, data);
    myModal.present();
}
```

The HTML is displaying a list of reminders using a ngFor (reminder of reminders). This method gets the string like this on html:

```
 <button ion-fab mini class="mini-button" (click)="editReminder($event, reminder)">
          <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
 </button>
```

If i console.log(data), it returns me the reminder like normal. But when i try to get it on the ReminderDetails modal:

```
export class ReminderDetailsPage {

   EditedReminder: string = this.navParams.get('data');
```

It simply returns undefined. I have imported navParams on both pages as well as declared them in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`this.modalCtrl.create(ReminderDetailsPage, { data: data });`

Pass an object to the `create()`-method.
And call `navParams.get()` in the `constructor` or in a lifecycle function like `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 0):

In Modal page

```
ionViewWillLoad() {
 const data = this.navParams.get('data');
 console.log(data);
}
```

If you want to pass data back out of modal..

```
import {NavParams, ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
...
    data: String
     constructor(private navParams: NavParams, private view: ViewController) {}
    ionViewWillLoad() {
     this.data = this.navParams.get('data');
     console.log(this.data);
    }

  closeModal() {
    this.view.dismiss(data);
  }
```

Then in calling page:

```
 const myModal: Modal = this.model.create('ModalPage', {data: myData})
 myModal.present();
 myModal.onWillDimiss(data) => {
     console.log(`About to dismiss with: ${data}`);
 })
 myModal.onDidDimiss(data) => {
     console.log(`Dismissed with: ${data}`);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case I suggest you use storage instead use NavParams